# MySQL time zone conversion issue

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, timestamp

**Is MySQL time zone conversion broken?**

I want to save java timestamp to DATETIME db field.

- DB timezone GMT
- Client timezone PST (GMT -07:00)
- useTimezone = true

Client time Jul 30, **09:00:00** (GMT-07:00)

In DB I got Jul 30, **02:00:00** (GMT)

Expected in GMT - Jul 30, **16:00:00** (GMT)

During debugging I found that conversion happens here

http://www.1java2c.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Database-JDBC-Connection-Pool/mysql/com/mysql/jdbc/TimeUtil.java.htm line 899

**Is that a real issue or it is my configuration fail?**

Comment: there is no simply "GMT" time zone, do you mean GMT+00:00?

Comment: I mean simply GMT which is valid from Java point of view

Comment: You might want to try `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` instead